# push branch tarball to github with git

Tags: git, github, tar

I have a git branch with let us say 2 directories, with some code files in it:

- htmlcode
- jscode

and I've made a tarball of this 2 directories in the same branch with Git. But to create a tarball with Git you need to do "git add htmlcode jscode"

The problem I now have is that it pushes all the files in my branch (i.e. htmlcode, jscode and the tarball) to Github. I know why this happens, but don't know how to make a work arround to push only the tarball to Github.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why would you want revision control on an archive?

Comment: It seems like you are using github as a backup storage. Normally you would want to put the code under git, and store the tarball somewhere for download, not the other way around.

Comment: Github already makes the tarball for download for you, on demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No part of this makes sense. Why are you using Git to generate the tarball, if you don't want to include the original files in Git?

Just use the tar/gzip commands themselves:

```
tar czf my-code.tar.gz htmlcode jscode
```

And then (if you really do want to do this) add the resulting file to Git:

```
git add my-code.tar.gz
git commit -m "Version-controlling a tarball for some unknown reason"
git push
```

That said, there's *no reason* to just be version-controlling the tarball. You really, *really* want to include the original source files in Git, and *exclude* the tarball. By only including the tarball, you're actually just hindering Git's built-in compression and rendering your repo more or less useless.